# Why does Java use modified UTF-8 instead of UTF-8?

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, java-native-interface

Why does Java use [modified UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Modified_UTF-8) rather than standard UTF-8 for object serialization and JNI?

One possible explanation is that modified UTF-8 can't have embedded null characters and therefore one can use functions that operate on null-terminated strings with it. Are there any other reasons?

Comment: i couild ask you why are you trying to read serialized java objects not in java :-)

Comment: @radai: I am not reading anything, just asking a question. =)

Comment: in that case i think NPE is right. looks like they use it whenever they need to interact with C (serialization, JNI, class file parsing)

Comment: This decision was made by an employee of Sun a very, very, very long time ago. Probably that person knows the answer, and no one else does. All you are going to get here is speculation.

Comment: And he'll take his secret to grave!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is faster and simpler for handling supplementary characters (by not handling them).

Java represent *characters* as 16 bit `char`s, but unicode has evolved to contain more than 64K characters. So some characters, the supplementary characters, has to be encoded in 2 `char`s (surrogate pair) in Java.

Strict UTF-8 requires that the encoder converts surrogate pairs into characters  then encode characters into bytes. The decoder needs to split supplementary characters back to surrogate pairs.

```
chars -> character -> bytes -> character -> chars
```

Since both ends are Java, we can take some shortcut and encode directly on the `char` level

```
char -> bytes -> char
```

neither encoder nor decoder need to worry about surrogate pairs.

Comment: A takeaway from this is to never use "modified UTF-8" (e.g. from DataOutputStream) for external storage that is not intended to be read back in from Java.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that's the main reason. In C land, having to deal with strings can contain embedded NULs would complicate things.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good description of Modified UTF-8 in [Unicode Explained - Page 306](http://books.google.com/books?id=PcWU2yxc8WkC&pg=PA306), but it does not explain **why** Modified UTF-8 was decided on.

There is also a very detailed explanation in Java's own documentation of how support for non-BMP Unicode characters was originally added to Java: [Supplementary Characters in the Java Platform](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/supplementary-142654.html).  But again, no explanation as to **why** Modified UTF-8 was decided on.

I don't think you are going to find a **why** unless you ask Java's architects directly.

Comment: That's a great description of _how_, but I don't see any info on _why_